# Delete line with specific numerical value

Tags: text-processing

I have a file that looks like this:

```
AA  110 B   2   ..  BB  3   ... BBB 3   D   F   3   D   D
AA  111 B   2   ..  BB  3   ... BBB 0   F   F   0   F   F
AA  112 C   2   ..  BB  3   ... BBB 0   D   F   0   D   F
AA  120 D   2   ..  FF  3   ... FFF 3   D   F   3   D   D
```

I would like to remove any line that contain the specific numerical value of 0. If I do:

```
sed '/0/d' infile > newfile
```

then lines 1 and 4 are deleted because they contain "0s" in 110 and 120. I tried other options with grep `grep -v '0' infile > newfile` or awk but no luck.

I'm sure there is a straightforward way for doing this but cannot find it. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `-w` to `grep` to do whole-word matching:

```
$ grep -vw 0 infile 
AA  110 B   2   ..  BB  3   ... BBB 3   D   F   3   D   D
AA  120 D   2   ..  FF  3   ... FFF 3   D   F   3   D   D
```

Answer (score 7):

Try *word boundary anchors*

```
sed '/\b0\b/d' file
AA  110 B   2   ..  BB  3   ... BBB 3   D   F   3   D   D
AA  120 D   2   ..  FF  3   ... FFF 3   D   F   3   D   D
```

Comment: Thanks! Works well! I believe grep is faster with large files than sed so I might go with the grep option.

Answer (score 2):

Update for tab delimited

```
sed '/\t0\t/d' infile > newfile
```

However, this one is safer:

```
sed '/\b0\b/d' infile > newfile
```

Comment: It may be that your whitespace is actually tabs, not spaces?

Comment: @AP38 There is no way that this couldn't work with the data you pasted. Maybe you have the tab delimited. I copied whatever you pasted and it's whitespace delimited.

Comment: Yes indeed, I forgot to mention that this is tab delimited. Not space

Comment: @AP38 I've updated version with the tab delimited. However anchors will be safer here.